# EF Core 2.0 ThenInclude with WHERE

Tags: c#, entity-framework

there happen to be the following relationship in my db:

cartentry -> product -> producttext <- culture

So, for every product, i can set a title, desc etc for each supported culture. Im switching from stored procedures to EF, and therefore i have to migrate a sp to get all items in the cart with the localized Name.

Well, i have the Feeling, this isnt too elegant:

```
public ActionResult Index(CartIndexViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.Cart = db.Cart
            .Include(cart => cart.Product)
                .ThenInclude(pt => pt.ProductText)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Culture)

            .Where(t => t.Token == ContextHelper.GetToken(HttpContext))
            .ToList();

        foreach (Model.Cart cart in vm.Cart)
        {
            Model.ProductText pt = cart.Product.ProductText.First(n => n.Culture.Name == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant());

            cart.Product.Title = pt.Title;
            cart.Product.Description = pt.Description;
            cart.Product.Link = pt.Link;
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Is there a more beautiful way of doing this? Especially get rid of the extra foreach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ef-core 2 has [global filters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/).

Comment: off-topic: `t.Token == ContextHelper.GetToken(HttpContext)` smells like a poor way to implement authorization. The data layer and the HttpContext should be well-separated.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: that did the trick!

Comment: @offtopic: What would be a better Approach? I need a Session-Token to look up items in the cart, do i?

Comment: I don't know what `ContextHelper.GetToken(HttpContext)` does and what it returns, but a token tends to be some security-related object, f.e. an OAuth bearer token, that's why it looks weird to use a "token" in your query.

Comment: ah ok, its just the session-id, but thank you for your thoughts on this. bad variable naming maybe.